# Google Charts Help - Trying to load JSON into Google Charts but the Chart is not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, charts, google-visualization

Im trying to load dummy data into my google charts, but somehow im getting no errors but the chart is not showing. Im still a beginner using this, and i cant see the issue.
Im loading the JSON data with jquery, and then ran through all data and inserted it as row to the chart.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <script>

      // onload callback - Script funktion til hvad Chart skal indeholde, og opsætning af data.
      function drawChart() {

        // JSONP request - Laver et API kald, hvor data'ene hentes ind.
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: 'http://nflarrest.com/api/v1/crime',
          data: {page: 1},
          dataType: 'jsonp',
        }).done(function (results) {

          // Opretter DataTable, som skal indeholde data'ene fra API'en i rows, samt kolonner.
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

          // Tilføjer kolonner til DataTable, først hvilket format det er (string, number, datetime osv.), dernæst navnet på kolonnen.
          data.addColumn('string', 'Category');
          data.addColumn('number', 'arrest_count');

          // Tilføjer rows til DataTable, med data'ene fra API'en.
          // Man skal huske de navne man tilføjer til row, skal være det samme som navnene fra API'en.
          for(i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
            data.addRow([
                parseFloat(results[i].Category),
                parseInt(results[i].arrest_count)
            ]);
          };


          // Instantiere Chart, hvilken type Chart det er, samt ID den tilgives.
          var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart($('#chart').get(0));

          // Opretter at Chart skal tegnes, med hvilke parametre den skal indholde, som de data der skal tegnes, samt info i Chart som fx en titel.
          chart.draw(data, {
            title: 'Wimp Weather Station'
          });

        });

      }

      // load chart lib
      google.load('visualization', '1', {
        packages: ['corechart']
      });

      // call drawChart once google charts is loaded
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Opretter Chart i div, med det ID den blev tildelt i Script -->
    <div id="chart" style="width: 100%;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/jvqh0ajh/119/

Comment: Im only using a string and a number. No dates. Also mine is loading from external JSON.

Answer (score 0):

you set the type of the first column as `'string'`

```
data.addColumn('string', 'Category');
```

yet the rows added are using type `'number'`

```
parseFloat(results[i].Category),
```

the types need to match, try it like this...

```
      for(i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
        data.addRow([
            results[i].Category,
            parseInt(results[i].arrest_count)
        ]);
      };
```

---

**UPDATE**

the following snippet is working for me...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://nflarrest.com/api/v1/crime/',
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function (jsonData) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    data.addColumn('string', 'Category');
    data.addColumn('number', 'arrest_count');

    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
      data.addRow([
        jsonData[i].Category,
        parseFloat(jsonData[i].arrest_count)
      ]);
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {
      height: 600,
      title: 'NFL Arrests'
    });
  }).fail(function (jqXHR, status) {
    console.log(status);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Gave me a bit better understanding. But its still not working.

Comment: Yes, its giving me no errors. Also showing the chart with no data.

Comment: Im not sure if it is a valid function, as its not printing anything in console? But still no errors.

Comment: When using the fail, im getting an error message now. https://i.gyazo.com/1376fd069342c590da2516826be62896.png

Comment: I found a solution. I recreated the done function with an succes and a function in the .ajax function. And now its working.